# C3.js Tooltips not Showing any text

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am using version 0.7.1 of `C3.js` and I have created a donut chart with the following code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['Critical', 100],
                ['High', 200],
                ['Informational', 300],
                ['Medium', 400],
                ['Low', 500],
            ],
            type : 'donut',
        },
        donut: {
            title: "Finding Severities"
        },
        tooltip: {
            format: {
                value: function (value, ratio, id, index) { return value + " " + id + " Findings"; }
            }
        }

    });
```

Everything works perfectly fine except for the tooltips which show up with blank boxes instead of the values I am trying to print. Even if I remove my custom tooltip format, the default tooltip still will not show up.

**I have not modified the `css` and `js` files for `C3.js`** and when I run this same code on their website (https://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html), it works perfectly fine.

Here is what shows up when I try to view the tooltip on my site:

[image]

And here is what I want to show up (which is what is supposed to happen if you run this code on https://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html) :

[image]

Comment: No it will still show an empty tooltip, even with the "tooltip" option removed

Comment: I wrote a fiddle from your code, it actually works as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/Lx91emjr/

Comment: Any ideas why it decides to stop working within my site? Could it have something to do with the way I am generating the chart? I am using all default c3.js files and settings which is why I am confused that its not working. I know the code is fine

Comment: Please look at this question's accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387455/loading-c3-js-into-an-html-file Notice how he declared CSS and JSs in his HTML markup. You should start from there, and then customize it.

Comment: I did that as well but still no luck.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No errors at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a full answer, but too big to fit in a comment:

Something, somewhere, is setting the css color style for your table cell elements to 'white' (or '#fff'). c3.css itself doesn't have a rule for this property, so this will be getting set in another css file you load in or it might be the default for whatever browser you are using.

The c3 demo page uses another css file, foundation.css, that sets it to '#222'. (And I can recreate your problem by changing that css file's value for that rule/property combo to 'white'). The jsfiddle linked above uses the browser default which for me in chrome is '#000'.

So add this css rule and I'm 90% sure the problem goes away:

```
.c3-tooltip td {
    color: #222;
}
```